# Django LDAP authentication fails: SERVER_DOWN

Tags: python, django, authentication, active-directory, django-auth-ldap

I'm using the `django-auth-ldap` for the authentication.

I'm having the following error:

`Caught LDAPError while authenticating xxx: SERVER_DOWN({'info': '(unknown error code)', 'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server"},)`

Using:
`AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS = { ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT : ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER }`

in `setting.py` should solve the problem, but it doesn't.

I played around and it looks like this option must be set before the connection is created. The `django_auth_ldap/backend.py` sets the options after the connections is set:

```
self._connection = self.ldap.initialize(self.settings.SERVER_URI)
for opt, value in self.settings.CONNECTION_OPTIONS.iteritems():
    self._connection.set_option(opt, value)
```

Using the django shell I only succeed if the `ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT`  is set in advance:

```
from django_auth_ldap.backend import LDAPBackend
ldapobj = LDAPBackend()
user = ldapobj.populate_user(username)
# ERROR:
# [12/Jun/2015 14:15:19] WARNING [django_auth_ldap:396] Caught LDAPError while authenticating xxx: SERVER_DOWN({'info': '(unknown error code)', 'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server"},)
if user is None:
    print "1st try failed!"
    ldapobj.ldap.set_option(ldapobj.ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldapobj.ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)
    user = ldapobj.populate_user(username)
    print user.is_anonymous()
```

Output:

```
 # 1st try failed!
 # False
```

Any idea what I have to do (without modifying the `django-auth-ldap` code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want [AUTH_LDAP_GLOBAL_OPTIONS](https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/reference.html#auth-ldap-global-options).

Comment: Link only answer with a dead link.

Comment: just for future references, this is the new link. https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#auth-ldap-global-options